# How to increase and decrease TextView font size in Android

Tags: android, textview

I have 2 buttons for increasing and decreasing `TextView` font size:

```
    btnZoomin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           txtview.setTextSize(txtview.getTextSize()+1);
        }
    });
    btnZoomout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtview.setTextSize(txtview.getTextSize()-1);
        }
    });
```

But are experiencing difficulty, as it will not work.

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340710/increasing-and-decreasing-the-font-sizes-of-the-android-application-by-user-sele) out

it worked perfectly with me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you see in the [DOCS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29) setTextSize needs 2 arguments: the [TypedValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html) and the new size.

Your code is fine, you just have to add the TypedValue :

```
txtview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,txtview.getTextSize()-1);
txtview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,txtview.getTextSize()+1);
```

Comment: 1-increase very large every time  2-doesnt decrease

Comment: try another typed value then , check which one your textview is using and replace on your code...

Comment: @MohamadRezaAtrian - Did you find any way out?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still facing the text size issue. You can use this code:

**To increase size:** `tvText.setTextSize(0, tvText.getTextSize() + 2.0f);`

**To decrease size**  `tvText.setTextSize(0, tvText.getTextSize() - 2.0f);`

Answer (score 2):

txtview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,txtview.getTextSize()-1);
txtview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,txtview.getTextSize()+1);

Answer (score 0):

Use this `text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);`

Comment: This will increase the text size and you can use sahil answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the previous code, that was wrong but i think this will work for you,

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter = 0;
private int size;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    counter = (int) txt.getTextSize();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), txt.getTextSize() + "",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            size = counter++;
            txt.setTextSize(size);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: i want increase and decrease size,not set a static value!!

Comment: every time that button clicked,textsize+1

Comment: i had updated the code, try this, it definitely work.

Comment: @sahil there is no diffrence between your code and his code