# Increasing and Decreasing the font sizes of the android application by user selection

Tags: android, textview, font-size, text-size

Actually i want to specify the custom text size in my application by user selection. Below is a figure that demonstrate the idea/theme

[image]

So, for that i have an idea to achieve this.

I will create a dialog in the view which having the user input options to increase/ decrease the font size. after changing the font size, i vll apply the same to the application. (+) & (-) signs will work to change the font size as well as seek bar too.

Here my question is is there any specific font style/ size changes in build android class / library / any other idea is available?

any help will be appreciate. mean while i will come with something which i try. Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check

```
btnTextDeSave.setOnClickListener(onClickEven);
btnTextInSave.setOnClickListener(onClickEven);

public OnClickListener onClickEven = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            break;
        case R.id.btTextDeSave:
            txtDescriptionSave.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (txtDescriptionSave.getTextSize() - 2f));
            break;
        case R.id.btTextInSave:
            txtDescriptionSave.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (txtDescriptionSave.getTextSize() + 2f));
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To increase the size of your `textView` you can use

```
_percentField.setTextSize(values[0]*2);
```

where `values` is an array.

And to decrease you can try

```
 _percentField.setTextSize(values[0]/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, <font-size value in integer> );

    // to update your changes
    textView.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by:

```
//Adjust values with whatever your need is
int SIZE_LARGE = 24; 
int SIZE_SMALL= 16;

btnLargeText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, LARGE_SIZE);
    }
});

btnSmallText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, SIZE_SMALL);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do it this way

```
float fs = prefs.getFloat("fontsize", 12);
seekbar.setProgress((int)fs);
layout.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,seekbar.getProgress());
```

and don't forget onProgressChanged:

```
layout.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,progress);
```